# Can I use finder methods in seed file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create data in seed file to test some behavior in my application, so can I use finder methods such as first and last to create another data?

**for example**

```
10.times { FirstModel.create(name: Faker::Lorem.word) }

SecondModel.create(some_fields..., first_model_ids = [FirstModel.first, FirstModel.last])
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Here's an example of using `seeds.rb` with `gem faker` that let's you populate the database with realistic fake data:

```
if User.find_by_email('admin@example.com').nil?
  admin = User.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'admin@example.com', password_confirmation: 'admin@example.com', confirmed_at: Time.now)
  #admin.skip_confirmation!
  admin.add_role(:admin) unless admin.has_role?(:admin)
  admin.add_role(:teacher) unless admin.has_role?(:teacher)
end

30.times do
  Client.create!([{
    first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
    last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
    phone_number: Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone,
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    gender: Faker::Gender.binary_type,
    date_of_birth: Faker::Date.birthday(min_age: 18, max_age: 65)
  }])
end

25.times do
  Event.create!([{
    starts_at: Faker::Time.between(from: 150.days.ago, to: Date.today),
    client_id: Client.first.id,
    status: "confirmed"
  }])
end
```

Note that I used `client_id: Client.first.id`, as well as `User.find_by_email` & `unless admin.has_role?(:admin)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, there’s nothing stopping you, but there’s a couple of other approaches you may find helpful...

You’re only using the id attribute to create you’re second models, so you don’t need to get the model instance for them all, you could get only the id attribute with the pluck method.

```
first_model_ids = FirstModel.pluck(:id)
```

You can then just dip in to the ids to use them when making your second models.

You could also do it without these finder methods at all. Because they’re being created in the same file, you could consider just keeping them in a variable. This way rails doesn’t have to ask the database for the newly created records.

Something like this.

```
first_models = 10.times.map do 
  FirstModel.create(name: Faker::Lorem.word)
end

SecondModel.create(
  other: ‘value’, 
  first_model_ids: [first_models[0].id, first_models[1].id]
)
```

This works because the map method (which works just like each or times) returns the result of the last statement in its block, in an array, for as many times as it’s run.

You could easily use map again to get all the ids:

```
first_model_ids = first_models.map {|fm| fm.id}
```

Or a beater syntax, which does exactly the same as the last example.

```
first_model_ids = first_models.map(&:id)
```